# Why to add process="@this" explicitly to p:commandButton to get action invoked?

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I know that we need to add explicitly `process="@this"` to get the `p:commandbutton` action get invoked and I also know that process attribute defaults to `@form` in primefaces.

Since process is defaulted to `@form` shouldn't the button also get processed along with the other elements in the form and its action should get invoked.

Can anyone explain the exact reason behind this?

Comment: Thanks a lot Balusc. I have read the link before posting this question itself and many of my doubts got clarified. But my doubt is since process defaults to form shouldn't the button get processed as one of all elements in the form?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If the validation fails for atleast one of form elements then JSF life cycle would directly render response by skipping Update Model values and Invoke application phase. So my doubt is if there are no validation errors shouldn't the button action get executed in the normal jsf lifecycle.

Comment: What's the source that says a commandButton must have `@this` to get processed? Do you have a working example that illustrates this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Process `@form` mean the current form of the `commandLink/Button`
Process `@this` mean the current component of the `commandLink/Button`. Check below code.

process.xhtml

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <h:inputText value="#{ProcessBean.id}" id="id"/><br/>
    <h:panelGroup id="panel_1">
        <h:inputText value="#{ProcessBean.name}" id="name"/><br/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="panel_2">
        <h:inputText value="#{ProcessBean.address}"/>
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton process="@form" value="Btm1" id="button1" action="#{ProcessBean.show}"/><!-- Default -->
        <p:commandButton process="@this" value="Btm2" id="button2" action="#{ProcessBean.show}"/>
        <p:commandButton process="@this form1:panel_1" value="Btm3" id="button3" action="#{ProcessBean.show}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

ProcessBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ProcessBean")
public class ProcessBean {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(address);
    }
}
```

Let's user input inputbox

```
001     -> id
Jone    -> name
London  -> address
```

Click `button1`, all `JSF component(Eg : id, name, address)` entire of the form will be process. Output will be :

```
001
Jone
London
```

Click `button2`, The process will be itself (Eg : button2). No process for `id, name, address`. Output will be:

```
null
null
null
```

Click `button3`, all `JSF component(Eg : name)`  entire of the `panel_1` and `button3` will be process. Output will be :

```
null
Jone
null
```

Does not invoke your action method? There might be validation or conversion failed before invoke.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really helpful.