# Why process="@this" needed for primefaces command button

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, cdi

Some of the command buttons' `actionListener` event of the xhtml page of my JSF app did not work until I added attribute `process="@this"` to the `<p:commandButton..` tag. I am wondering why. I haven't seen this in any example. I am using a combination of JSF 2.2 & CDI, along with Primefaces 5.0 on JBoss 7.1 runtime. My beans are CDI `@javax.inject.Named` beans and scope is `@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't have to!

The default behaviour of PrimeFaces commandButton is `process="@form"` thus the whole form will be processed. If the actionListener does not get invoked when you change the behavior to `process="form"` explicitly, but gets invoked when you change it to `process="@this"` then this usually indicates some validation error or similar.

To test this just add an `<p:messages autoUpdate="true">` into your page and you will see all error messages that may have occured.

Fix those confirmation and/or validation erros and you will see, that your action is beeing invoked, even if you do not add the process-Attribute explicitly.

Comment: That helped, and pushed forth a pure newbie like me.

Comment: I tried another page with no validations this time. And there seems to be a problem. Please have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821562/jsf-page-why-no-validations-yet-process-attribute-required

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation of why you need to add attribute `process="@this"` to your `<p:commandButton>` : [Why to add process="@this" explicitly to p:commandButton to get action invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234918/why-to-add-process-this-explicitly-to-pcommandbutton-to-get-action-invoked)