# JSF page - Why no validations yet process attribute required?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

The command button's `actionListener` event of the following JSF based xhtml page does not work. I do not have any validations on the page. The event only works when I add attribute `process="@this"` to button tag. As there are no validations, so I do not even get any validation error. But with process attribute I get success message returned by java side handler method. So I am kind of stuck without unwanted process attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body style="margin:0 auto !important;width:80% !important;">
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:panel id="rootPanel"
        style="background-color:#E8E8E8 ;width=90%;padding:10px;margin:10px;border:2px solid black;">
        <p:panel id="logoHeaderPanel"
            style="background-color:#E8E8E8 ;width=70%;padding:30px;margin:30px;border:1px solid black;">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="./headerImage.gif"  />
                <h:outputLabel style="font-size:2.1em;margin-left:30px"
                    value="Demo App" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
          <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true"/>
        <p:panel id="mainContentPanel"
            style="background-color:#E8E8E8 ;width=70%;padding:60px;margin:30px;border:1px solid black;">
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <h:outputLabel for="a" value="State Search" style="margin:10px;" />
                <p:inputText id="a" value="" style="margin:10px;" />
                <h:outputLabel for="b" value="Value" style="margin:10px;" />
                <p:inputText id="b" value="" style="margin:10px;" />

                <h:outputLabel for="c" value="City Search" style="margin:10px;" />
                <p:inputText id="c" value="" style="margin:10px;" />
                <h:outputLabel for="d" value="Value" style="margin:10px;" />
                <p:inputText id="d" value="" style="margin:10px;" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="float:right;">
                <p:commandButton style="height:80px;" value="Generate Report"
                            id="reporting" actionListener="#{sampleBean.handlerMethod}" update="a"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Java side code

```
public void handlerMethod(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Inside Listener");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage("Success! Action called."));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `value=""` in the `p:inputText`. If you do not want to specify value, you should remove attribute `value=""`.

```
<p:inputText id="a" style="margin:10px;" />
```